# Spring 3.1.1 with hibernate 4.1 annotations configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I am setting up the new project with spring3.1.1 and hibernate 4.1.
When I run my project I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
at com.humancapital.dao.TestModelDAOImpl.getTestModelList(TestModelDAOImpl.java:22)
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

       
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
                                      
        <!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions  -->    
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
                                      
        <!-- PropertyConfiguer -->
        <bean id="propertyCongigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/config/jdbc/jdbc.properties"></property>
        </bean>
        
        <!--  DataSource connection -->
        <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></property>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>  
        </bean>
        
        <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"></property>
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.humancapital.dao.TestModel</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
            </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        

        
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
        </bean>
        
        <context:annotation-config/>
        
        <bean id="testModelDAO" class="com.example.dao.TestModelDAOImpl"></bean>
```

### MyDAOImpl

```
@Repository
public class TestModelDAOImpl implements TestModelDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public List getTestModelList() {
    System.out.println(sessionFactory.toString());
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TestModel.class).list();
}
}
```

I have added my dependency jars please suggest me

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
antlr-runtime-3.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ejb3-persistence-3.3.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.8.5.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
json-lib-2.3-jdk13.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
mail.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
servlet-api.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar
spring-modules-validation-0.7.jar
standard.jar
```

Please Help me to complete the project setup.
Please give some suggestion where we need to concentrate while setting up the new project structure where fewer changes are necessary for future up gradation.

Sorry I am new to stackoverflow I don’t know how to give replay to the commands

Comment: Have you tried it without the propagation setting?

Comment: Why do you need `hibernateManagedSession=true`?

Comment: I have tried it without propagation but still I am getting same exception.

Comment: When I remove the hibernateMessageSession= true it’s giving the exception 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens becuase you have hibernate.`current_session_context_class` property enabled

you should NEVER use that property when combining Hibernate with Spring that destroys proper session and transaction management. The only time you want to set this property is if you use Spring and Hibernate in a JTA environment, else don't use it.

Comment: Thanks danny.lesnik when I remove the line I am getting No Session found for current thread exception 

org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1039)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Where id your transaction? It looks like you are trying to run ot out of transaction scope.

Comment: Thanks danny.lesnik. I have added the @Transactional(readOnly=true,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) in my code finally it's working fine.

Comment: I suggest you to use Propagation.REQUIRES instead.

Comment: Ok danny.lesnik if suggest some book's for hibernate core it’s very helpful for me. I have googled some tutorials but still I am not getting proper book for hibernate. Thanks.                        Sorry for my English

Comment: current_session_context_class indeed caused all sorts of problems, a complete nightmare.